# Index formatting with footnote number has clashed with "See" and "See also"

Tags: hyperref, indexing, makeindex

I am facing an issue in tagging the index for `See`, `See also` and some index terms which are in footnotes. Index representing within the footnote was to be reproduced along with footnote number in the Index page.

Here `\hyperindexformat` has clashed with `See` and `See also`. I am representing `See` and `See also` as dot `.` separator. However, it is affecting the index tag which was in footnote with footnote number. Please see my `Sample_Book.mst` file:

```
preamble "\\begin{theindex}
\\markboth{\\fontsize{9.5}{11.5}\\selectfont Index}{\\fontsize{9.5}{11.5}\\selectfont Index}
\\thispagestyle{empty}
\\addtocontents{toc}{\\protect\\contentsline {chapter}{Index}{\\rmfamily\\bfseries\\thepage}{page.\\thepage}}\n"
delim_0 "\\idxdelim"
delim_1 "\\idxdelim"
delim_2 "\\idxdelim"
delim_n "\\idxdelim"
delim_r "--"
```

And my TeX file `Sample_Book.tex` is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[width=4.375in, height=7.0in, top=1.0in, papersize={5.5in,8.5in}]{geometry}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tipa}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{makeidx}


\gdef\indexcomma{, }
\def\indexcommaoff{\let\indexcomma\relax}
\gdef\indexcommaon{\def\indexcomma{, }}
\providecommand\Seename{See}
\providecommand\Seealsoname{See also}
\newcommand{\See}[2]{\emph{\Seename} #1}
\newcommand{\Seealso}[2]{\emph{\Seealsoname} #1}
\newcommand{\pageandfn}[2]{\hyperpage{#2}\textit{n}#1}    % format as <page><italic>n</italic><footnotemark>
\newcommand{\indexfn}[1]{\index{#1|pageandfn{\thefootnote}}}
\makeindex
\makeatletter
\def\idxdelim{\@ifnextchar{\hyperindexformat}{.\space}{\@ifnextchar{\hyperindexformat}{.\space}{,\space}}}
\def\idxdelimfn{\@ifnextchar{\hyperindexformat}{,\space}{}}
\makeatother
\RequirePackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\hyperindexformat}[1]{#1}


\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{\thesection\ #1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\bfseries\thepage}
\fancyhead[LO]{\bfseries\rightmark}
\fancyhead[RE]{\bfseries\leftmark}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\addtolength{\headheight}{0.5pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{0in}
\renewcommand{\footruleskip}{0pt}
\fancypagestyle{plain}{%
\fancyhead{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
}
\parskip 0.05in
\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\tableofcontents
\mainmatter
\chapter{Subjectivation and Objectivation}
In human history\index{Subjectivation} no\index{Feb} philosopher or sage explained the cosmic mystery and the spiritual reality more rationally than Shrii Shrii Anandamurti (1921-1990) \cite{baba_books} \cite{anandamitra}. His rational outlook is truly inspiring.

In writing,\footnote{This is sample PDF\indexfn{Writing}} the words point and purpose are almost synonymous. Your point is your purpose, and how you decide to make your point clear to your reader is also\index{Principle} your purpose. Writers have a point and a purpose for every paragraph that they create.

Writers\index{Jan} write\index{Feb} descriptive paragraphs because their purpose is to describe something. Their point is that something is beautiful or disgusting or strangely intriguing. Writers write persuasive and argument paragraphs because their purpose is to persuade or convince someone. Their point is that their reader should see things a particular way and possibly take action on that new way of seeing things. Writers write paragraphs of comparison because the comparison will make their point clear to their readers.


\chapter{Description of the Principle}
The purpose of Pattern Based Writing: Quick \& Easy Essay\footnote{This is sample PDF\indexfn{Principle}} is to quickly and easily teach students how to organize information and make points clear. Then in the Writing with Purpose section of the writing program, students learn to apply their new writing strategies to different types, kinds, genres, and modes of writing. The truth is that it's quick and easy\index{Jan} to get students to write many different types of paragraphs when they have the right foundation.

Put simply, all of the different types and kinds of paragraphs simply involve layering on a different purpose or intent. When students have the right foundation, it's just that simple. What are you trying to achieve in this paragraph and in your whole composition? What is your purpose right here? Do you wish to describe? Do you want to evaluate? Is your goal to narrate? Is your intent to persuade?


\chapter{Creation of Cosmos as Objectivation}
Sunset is the time of day when our sky meets the outer space solar winds. There are blue, pink, and purple swirls, spinning and twisting, like clouds of balloons caught in a whirlwind. The sun moves slowly to hide behind the line of horizon, while the moon races to take its place in prominence atop the night sky. People slow to a crawl, entranced, fully forgetting the deeds that must still be done. There is a coolness, a calmness, when the sun does set.

On July 16, 1969, the Apollo 11 spacecraft launched from the Kennedy Space Center in Florida. Its mission was to go where no human being had gone before--the moon! The crew consisted of Neil Armstrong, Michael Collins, and Buzz Aldrin. The spacecraft landed on the moon in the Sea of Tranquility, a basaltic flood plain, on July 20, 1969. The moonwalk took place the following day. On July 21, 1969, at precisely 10:56 EDT, Commander Neil Armstrong emerged from the Lunar Module and took his famous first step onto the moon's surface. He declared, ``That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind.'' It was a monumental moment in human history!

\chapter{More on Cosmic Subjectivation}
On July 16, 1969, the Apollo 11 spacecraft launched from the Kennedy Space Center in Florida. Its mission was to go where no human being had gone before--the moon! The crew consisted of Neil Armstrong, Michael Collins, and Buzz Aldrin. The spacecraft landed on the moon in the Sea of Tranquility, a basaltic flood plain, on July 20, 1969. The moonwalk took place the following day. On July 21, 1969, at precisely 10:56 EDT, Commander Neil Armstrong emerged from the Lunar Module and took his famous first step onto the moon's surface. He declared, ``That's one small step for man, one giant leap for mankind.'' It was a monumental moment in human history!


\backmatter
%
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{baba_books}
Books of Shrii Shrii Anandamurti (Prabhat Ranjan Sarkar): \\
http://shop.anandamarga.org/
\bibitem{anandamitra}
Avtk. Ananda Mitra Ac., \emph{The Spiritual Philosophy of Shrii Shrii Anandamurti: A Commentary on Ananda Sutram}, Ananda Marga Publications (1991) \\
ISBN: 81-7252-119-7
\end{thebibliography}

\index{Jan|See{January}}

\index{Feb|Seealso{February}}

\printindex

\end{document}
```

Please see my index page:

[image]

I am tagging index terms for getting along footnote indicator (number) was `\indexfn`. The command `\idxdelim`, I cannot configure for index terms with the footnote indicator (number).

How can I change `Principle, 1. 3n1` to `Principle, 1, 3n1` and `Writing. 1n1` to `Writing, 1n1`?

After creating the index, I manually changed `\idxdelim` to `\idxdelimfn` for index term for footnote number.

Answer (score 1):

I have copied `hyperref.sty` to my current TeX file working directory, then i changed the line `#1|hyperindexformat{/#2#3}` to `1|#2#3` from `hyperref.sty` for doesn't produce `\hyperindexformat` command in the Index file. And i redefine the `\idxdelim` command in the TeX file

```
\def\idxdelim{\@ifnextchar{\See}{.\space}
    {\@ifnextchar{\Seealso}{.\space}{,\space}}}
```

By finding the Next Charter of `\idxdelim` was `\See` or `\Seealso` it produce dot space `.\space` else comma space `,\space`